# Replace XML tags by numbers

Tags: bash, sed, awk, xml

Suppose i have an xml like this

```
<a>
  hey
  how
  are
</a>
<a>
  where 
  are
  you
</a>
```

I want to change them and assign number like this--

```
1.hey
  how
  are

2.where 
  are
  you
```

I would prefer the answer in bash, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question doesn't fit this site.

Comment: Thanks. Even if i want the solution in bash?

Comment: Alright, you may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015766/12524487). But your example is not a valid XML file (it contains multiple root elements), so `xmllint` may be of little help to you.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar text processing questions are perfectly on topic here. On the other hand, using Bash itself for text processing is not recommended...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an arbitrarily named root element, you can use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet), because it is generally not a good idea to process XML files with `awk` or `sed` - the task at hand can easily be achieved by the following one-line command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//a" -v "concat(position(),'. ',.)" input.xml
```

Its output is:

```
1. 
  hey
  how
  are
2. 
  where 
  are
  you
```

Removing the first line-break would be complicated.
If you really want to do it, you can try

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//a" -v "concat(position(),'. ',substring-after(.,'  '))" a.xml
```

but this is tailored to the given XML sample.